# Why is my VSCode intelliSense providing false errors only when using SSH?

Tags: c++, linux, macos, visual-studio-code, virtual-machine

I am running an Ubuntu 20 VM on VMware Fusion (12.2.4) on my Macbook Pro (OSX 12.6.1). To edit, I use VSCode (1.74.3) on my Macbook host and SSH into the Ubuntu VM as it runs smoother. I've struggled with configuring the include paths in the c_cpp_properties.json file to get all of my includes recognized by intelliSense. The struggle being that I have had to use redundant and specific paths for includes not recognized when using the recursive method on their respective parent directories. C++ is the primary coding language used in this project.

I am now faced with a very annoying issue only occurring on the host's VSCode. Using VSCode directly within the VM, I have discovered that this issue does not exist. Moreover, the code compiles and runs with no errors.

My issue is that I am getting multiple errors from intelliSense upon calling members from a class, it says that the members of this class do not exist when indeed they do.

My working file is CPFA_controller.cpp (with a header file of the same name). The class whose members I am calling is defined in separate cpp and header, CPFA_loop_functions.cpp (with a header file of the same name).

I will now include snips of the code to show how the classes are being called/initialized and show the includes. I do not wish to disclose the entire code as this is an academic project and wish to keep the core functionality confidential. If any additional/specific info is needed (e.g. syntax) I can provide it upon request. To the best of my knowledge, I am including what I believe is most relative to the issue.

CPFA_controller.h

```
#ifndef CPFA_CONTROLLER_H
#define CPFA_CONTROLLER_H

#include <source/Base/BaseController.h>
#include <source/Base/Pheromone.h>
#include <source/CPFA/CPFA_loop_functions.h>
/* Definition of the LEDs actuator */
#include <argos3/plugins/robots/generic/control_interface/ci_leds_actuator.h>

// Ryan Luna 12/28/22
#include <source/Base/QuarantineZone.h>
#include <source/Base/Food.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace argos;

static unsigned int num_targets_collected = 0;

class CPFA_loop_functions;

class CPFA_controller : public BaseController {

    // some code 
}
```

CPFA_loop_functions.h

```
#ifndef CPFA_LOOP_FUNCTIONS_H
#define CPFA_LOOP_FUNCTIONS_H

#include <argos3/core/simulator/loop_functions.h>
#include <argos3/plugins/robots/foot-bot/simulator/footbot_entity.h>
#include <argos3/core/simulator/entity/floor_entity.h>
#include <source/CPFA/CPFA_controller.h>
#include <argos3/plugins/simulator/entities/cylinder_entity.h>
#include <source/Base/Food.h>   // Ryan Luna 11/10/22

using namespace argos;
using namespace std;

static const size_t GENOME_SIZE = 7; // There are 7 parameters to evolve

class CPFA_loop_functions : public argos::CLoopFunctions
{

    friend class CPFA_controller;
    friend class CPFA_qt_user_functions;

        // some code
}
```

In CPFA_controller.cpp the following is an example of how I am calling members of the CPFA_loop_functions class. This is the file with the aforementioned false errors. The object name of the CPFA_loop_functions class is LoopFunctions.

```
void CPFA_controller::SetLocalResourceDensity() {
    argos::CVector2 distance;

    // remember: the food we picked up is removed from the foodList before this function call
    // therefore compensate here by counting that food (which we want to count)
    ResourceDensity = 1;

    /* Calculate resource density based on the global food list positions. */
    for(size_t i = 0; i < LoopFunctions->FoodList.size(); i++) {
        distance = GetPosition() - LoopFunctions->FoodList[i].GetLocation();    // modified ** Ryan Luna 11/11/22

        // Local food found
        if(distance.SquareLength() < LoopFunctions->SearchRadiusSquared*2) {
            ResourceDensity++;
            LoopFunctions->FoodList[i].SetColor(argos::CColor::ORANGE); // modified ** Ryan Luna 11/11/22
            LoopFunctions->ResourceDensityDelay = SimulationTick() + SimulationTicksPerSecond() * 10;

            // Add to lcoal food list to give to nest       // Ryan Luna 01/24/23
            AddLocalFood(LoopFunctions->FoodList[i]);
        }
    }

/* Set the fidelity position to the robot's current position. */
    SiteFidelityPosition = GetPosition();
    isUsingSiteFidelity = true;
    updateFidelity = true; 
    TrailToShare.push_back(SiteFidelityPosition);
    LoopFunctions->FidelityList[controllerID] = SiteFidelityPosition;
```

The intelliSense reports the false errors when calling the FoodList member (a vector of "Food" objects, where "Food" is a defined class in its own separate file). The respective errors are:

```
[{
    "resource": "/home/ryan/cpfa-dos/CPFA/source/CPFA/CPFA_controller.cpp",
    "owner": "C/C++2",
    "code": "135",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "class \"argos::CVector2\" has no member \"GetLocation\"",
    "source": "C/C++",
    "startLineNumber": 742,
    "startColumn": 57,
    "endLineNumber": 742,
    "endColumn": 68
},{
    "resource": "/home/ryan/cpfa-dos/CPFA/source/CPFA/CPFA_controller.cpp",
    "owner": "C/C++2",
    "code": "135",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "class \"argos::CVector2\" has no member \"SetColor\"",
    "source": "C/C++",
    "startLineNumber": 747,
    "startColumn": 31,
    "endLineNumber": 747,
    "endColumn": 39
},{
    "resource": "/home/ryan/cpfa-dos/CPFA/source/CPFA/CPFA_controller.cpp",
    "owner": "C/C++2",
    "code": "135",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "class \"argos::CVector2\" has no member \"GetType\"",
    "source": "C/C++",
    "startLineNumber": 649,
    "startColumn": 39,
    "endLineNumber": 649,
    "endColumn": 46
},{
    "resource": "/home/ryan/cpfa-dos/CPFA/source/CPFA/CPFA_controller.cpp",
    "owner": "C/C++2",
    "code": "135",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "class \"argos::CVector2\" has no member \"GetLocation\"",
    "source": "C/C++",
    "startLineNumber": 645,
    "startColumn": 63,
    "endLineNumber": 645,
    "endColumn": 74
}]
```

I also receive an error in the CPFA_controller.cpp code sample when calling the FidelityList member (a vector of "Pheromone" objects, where "Pheromone" is also a class defined in a separate file). The respective error:

```
[{
    "resource": "/home/ryan/cpfa-dos/CPFA/source/CPFA/CPFA_controller.cpp",
    "owner": "C/C++2",
    "code": "135",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "class \"CPFA_loop_functions\" has no member \"FidelityList\"",
    "source": "C/C++",
    "startLineNumber": 760,
    "startColumn": 20,
    "endLineNumber": 760,
    "endColumn": 32
}]
```

In CPFA_controller.cpp, there are 31 of these issues all of the same nature regarding the CPFA_loop_functions class. There are no other errors reported in any of the code in any other file. Reiterating, these errors or not reported on the VSCode running on the VM. As well, the code compiles and runs with no errors.

c_cpp_properties.json

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "/usr/include/lua5.3",
                "/usr/include/argos3/**",
                "~/argos-sir-sim/**",
                "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtWidgets",
                "/usr/include/argos3/plugins/simulator/visualizations/qt-opengl",
                "~/cpfa-dos/**"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/gcc",
            // "cStandard": "gnu17",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            // "cppStandard": "gnu++14",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            // "intelliSenseMode": "linux-gcc-x64"
            "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

settings.json

```
{
    "cmake.sourceDirectory": "${workspaceFolder}/.vscode/extensions/twxs.cmake-0.0.17/node_modules/peg-cmake/test",
    "files.associations": {
        "GA1DArrayGenome.C": "cpp",
        "initializer_list": "cpp"
    },
    "editor.quickSuggestions": {
        "other": "on",
        "comments": "off",
        "strings": "off"
      },
    "editor.parameterHints.enabled": false,
    "editor.suggest.snippetsPreventQuickSuggestions": false,
    "html.suggest.html5": false,
}
```

Please let me know of any additional information needed.

I have tried using redundant include paths in c_cpp_properties.json. This took care of any stubborn include issues but the aforementioned issue remains.

I changed the cStandard, cppStandard, and intelliSenseMode attributes to match those used in the [VSCode Linux GCC Tutorial](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-linux) but nothing changed.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Given that it works when VS Code is within the container, you may be looking for the VS Code Remote Container Dev environment feature. Note that the container does not have to be on another machine, it's more that the container is considered remote to the computer. You could do it on another machine too though

You can see more here:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/devcontainers/containers

I have specifically tested this feature using Apptainer with VS Code and the ARGoS3 Simulator. Though it is a hack to make the Docker container solution work with Apptainer.
Additional references:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/3066
https://medium.com/@dcat52/2526380a4673